# Azure Artifacts - 401 unauthorized error when some users access to organization-scoped feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

**Background**

Hi, I have a organization with many projects in Azure Devops. One of the project created a organization-scoped feed and built some pipelines do NPM publish to the feed. We can see the packages appear in the feed now. We then follow the instruction in "Connect to feed" to restore package.

*.npmrc file*

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/registry/

always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/registry/:username=[ANY_VALUE_BUT_NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/:username=[ANY_VALUE_BUT_NOT_AN_EMPTY_STRING]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

**Problem**

I as a project administrator can successfully restore package(npm install). However, some users cannot restore and show up "401 unauthorized" after entering command. I have checked the view setting and the .npmrc file as well as PAT with a narrow scope of Packaging (read and write).

I have also checked [Manage packages with feed permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops). It said List, install, and restore packages only require "Reader" permission. I added the user into the Reader Group in Project level and Reader Group in Feed Setting.

**What Could be Missing?**

**Update**
To share my pipeline detail:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "10.x"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: "install"
      workingDir: <Dir>

  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: "publish"
      workingDir: <Dir>
      publishRegistry: "useFeed"
      publishFeed: <Feed>
```

Comment: Hi @Kwan, Which task are you using to restore the package, NPM or run the npm install command? Could you share the detail log here? In addition, if you run the cmd local, you could also try to open a terminal and run `vsts-npm-auth -F -C .npmrc` to refresh the token and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Do u mean the pipeline? I have used 
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'

Comment: Hi @Kwan, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines), please click the button `Allow project-scoped builds` then try it again. Since you are using the package in the pipeline, it will install the package via service account instead of user account. Also you could check [this](https://www.code4it.dev/blog/connect-npm-feeds-from-azure-devops#solving-error-e401---unable-to-authenticate) then kindly share the result here.

Comment: but the button is disabled.

Comment: Hi @Kwan, Please check the answer below and kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kwan, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have set up feed permissions, but you are not using it in the pipeline, check the pic below.

[image]

Update your yaml build as below:

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: '{Dir}'
    customRegistry: 'useFeed'
    customFeed: '{Feed}'
```

Comment: I don't want to make change these days since I am afraid it will introduce error to existed users. I will try later. Could you please explain some more? I have already published to the feed and why the above changes make users able to access?

Comment: Hi @Kwan, There are two ways to install an npm package in the Azure DevOps, install the package via feed or .npmrc file, we need to specify how to install it in task. And it install package in the pipeline via service account instead of personal account. If you are using self-hosted agent, you could change the service account to your personal account, then it should also work. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714238/cicd-for-mds-via-azure-devops/65729877#65729877)

Comment: Hi, Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here